# How to sign EIP712 hashed message on Keystone?

Tags: eip712

I want to create an app for hardware wallets like Ledger and Keystone.

Currently, I have a problem with signing hashed EIP712 messages on Keystone. I can't create the correct bc-ur for Keystone. I use [EthSignRequest.constructETHRequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@keystonehq/bc-ur-registry-eth?activeTab=code) for constructing bc-ur.

For Ledger, I use the function [signEIP712HashedMessage](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-live/tree/develop/libs/ledgerjs/packages/hw-app-eth#signeip712hashedmessage) to sign, and it works correctly.

How can I do the same for Keystone?

Useful links:

- [Keystone Developer Hub Integration Guide](https://github.com/KeystoneHQ/Keystone-developer-hub/blob/main/Integration_guide.md)
- [ERC-4527: QR Code transmission protocol](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4527)